# Need sql commands to automatically execute each line in batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

Trying to set up batch file to automatically execute sql commands. Can type them manually, but cannot figure out how to get it to run each line by itself.
This is what I have (need to set sa user automatically:

```
sqlcmd -E
EXEC sp_password NULL, 'newpassword', 'sa' -b
go
```

Also tried osql and nothing. Tried different options with no luck.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What OS?  OSQL is old and deprecated.  This should get you going for modern OS's (untested).

```
@ECHO OFF
SQLCMD /? > nul 2> nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO.SQLCMD not found on this machine.  This program will now exit.
   PAUSE
   GOTO :eof
   )

REM add -h-1 if you don't want header
REM Remove REM below for SA
REM  SET SQLCmdLine=SQLCMD -B -W400 -U "YourUserName" -P "YourPassword" -S "YourServer" -D "YourDatabase" 
REM Remove REM below for Windows Auth
REM SET SQLCmdLine=SQLCMD -B -w400 -E -S "YourServer" -D "YourDatabase"   

REM Now you can do stuff like
REM %SQLCmdLine% -Q "SELECT * FROM.....
```

Comment: Thanks. However I want to use Windows authentication in order to change the sa password without having/knowing it..
The reason being, is a temporary fix for customers of ours who have port 80 open, and something is getting in our Servers changing sa password, thus requiring us to have to manually keep changing it back. We recommend secure port 443 but most don't bother to have it changed.

Comment: Sounds like that would be a serious security flaw if it were possible!

Comment: Windows 7 or Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Meet my friend google...  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/how-to-change-password-visually-and-programmatically-in-sql/

Comment: How would I implement my code into your script to run? Using Win Auth

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I need to have it run in a batch file so I can schedule it to run automatically or on startup, without having to Open SQL in any way..

Comment: OK... I editd my code to show both (for others).  For what you are doing set Database to Master.  Then do something like the post with ALTER LOGIN.   WARNING!  You should do this on a test box and test thoroughly first, because obviously I have not!

Comment: Figured it out. But have to wait to allow to post answer later. Thanks again for your help and time sir!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out linking to a sql file.

reset.bat file:

```
sqlcmd -E -i C:\reset_sa_pw.sql
```

reset_sa_pw.sql (located root of C) file:

```
EXEC sp_password NULL, 'newpassword', 'sa'
go
```

Thanks for everyone's help!